# How to make a div container automatically fit it's child element with fixed size in IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jquery UI dialog to show some label-field pairs, the field could be a `textarea` and has a pre-configured fixed size.

I set the width and height of the UI dialog to `auto`, so it can fit different sizes.

The HTML inside UI dialog looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="content-label">
      <span id="msg-label" class="label">Message</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <span class="message-body">
        <textarea style="height: 152px; width:256px;" class="msg-textarea" maxlength="255" placeholder="Message Body" ></textarea>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the width of label `<div class="content-label">` was set to 90px and `<div class="content-field">` has 100px left margin to make them in one row.

The CSS:

```
.content-row .content-label {
  width: 90px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content-row .content-field {
  font-size:13px;
  margin-left:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.msg-textarea {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The code works for Chrome and Firefox, but not for IE11, in IE11, `<div class="content-field">` takes more horizontal spaces that the textarea, looks the width of the div equals the width of textarea plus the width of lable.

Edit: I would keep the `margin-left:100px` because it's not only for spacing, it's important for another functionalities, and it needs to be kept.

Edit: adding jquery UI dialog tag, may be the UI dialog calculate the content width in a wrong way on IE11?

I am wondering if there is a way to make this solution work for IE 11 as well? Thanks!

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq0jqLsw/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: remove  `margin-left:100px;` from `.content-row .content-field`.
here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq0jqLsw/2/). hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I didn't make it clear, the margin is not only for spacing, it plays a role for other functionalities, so I have to keep the margin. otherwise I would take this solution already.

Comment: no, actually now I suspect it is the UI dialog who did the wrong calculation about the content width on IE.